# AWS Elastic Beanstalk doesn't reduce load balancer to zero instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a test and prod environment, both built using elastic beanstalk.   I would like to reduce the test application load balancer instance size to 0, ie switch it off at a certain time.

I have setup a schedule in AWS to do this (see image):

[image]

However, when I look at the EC2 instances (current utc time 2:53) it clearly isn't working:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: If you go to console EC2->Auto Scaling Groups->Scheduled Actions, do you see the scheduled scaling policy there for your test auto scaling group.

Comment: You should also be able to see the Auto Scaling history tab in the Auto Scaling, which might give some hints as to what is happening. By the way, the system is not changing the Load Balancer. Rather, it is launching or terminating Amazon EC2 instances to which the Load Balancer serves traffic.

Comment: Thank you both for your help.   After looking at the history, I found that it was facing at the 23:15 schedule with the following message:

Comment: Executing scheduled action awseb-Reduc-19LNLER57R8WK. Status Reason: Max bound, 0, must be greater than or equal to OnDemandBaseCapacity, 1.

Comment: For this reason, I am going to change my on demand base capacity to zero and see what happens.   Many thanks